# How can I sort a vector of bigz integers in R?

Tags: r, sorting, arbitrary-precision

I am working in `R` using arbitrary precision arithmetic in the [`gmp` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html).  This package creates and stores large integers in the `bigz` form.  For example, you can create a vector of arbitrarily large integers as follows:

```
X <- as.bigz(c("734876349856913169345", "610034193791098", "82348779011105371828395319",
               "810367198176345917234", "92573840155289", "729811850143511981", "51385",
               "358934723", "751938475", "72265018270590", "12838756105612376401932875"));
```

I would like to sort this vector of large integers (smallest to largest).  Although the documentation for `bigz` objects notes that they can be compared with inequality operations, unfortunately the standard `sort` function does not work on them:

```
sort(X)
Error in rank(x, ties.method = "min", na.last = "keep") : 
  raw vectors cannot be sorted
```

**Question:** How can I take a `bigz` vector like the one above and sort it in ascending order?

Comment: Sadly, there's a lot of set & order - related funcs that `gmp` doesn't support.   In the spirit of smartassness, I'll suggest writing a "bubble-sort" algo :-).   The "convert to character" seems to be the only current way to `sort`, or to do things like `intersect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It involves coercing to string and back but you could possibly use `str_sort()`.  The argument `numeric = TRUE` gives a natural rather than alphanumeric sort order.

```
library(stringr)
library(gmp)

as.bigz(str_sort(BIGINTEGERS, numeric = TRUE))
Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 11:
 [1] 51385                      358934723                  751938475                  72265018270590             92573840155289             610034193791098           
 [7] 729811850143511981         734876349856913169345      810367198176345917234      12838756105612376401932875 82348779011105371828395319
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `mixedsort` from `gtools` after converting to `character`

```
as.bigz(gtools::mixedsort(as.character(BIGINTEGERS)))
#Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 11:
# [1] 51385                      358934723                  751938475                 
# [4] 72265018270590             92573840155289             610034193791098           
# [7] 729811850143511981         734876349856913169345      810367198176345917234     
#[10] 12838756105612376401932875 82348779011105371828395319
```

as  methods for class 'bigz' include `as.character`

```
grep('as.character', methods(class = 'bigz'), fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE)
#[1] "as.character.bigz"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to do this by first grouping the big integers by number of digits, then sorting each group as a character vector. It's not exactly elegant, but it works:

```
library(gmp)
X <- as.bigz(c("734876349856913169345", "610034193791098", "82348779011105371828395319",
               "810367198176345917234", "92573840155289", "729811850143511981", "51385",
               "358934723", "751938475", "72265018270590", "12838756105612376401932875"))

sortbigz <- function(N, decreasing = FALSE) { 
  stopifnot(is.bigz(N))
  # returns a list with the following:
  #  [[1]] a bigz vector, sorted as if NA represented infinity
  #  [[2]] the original argument, converted to a character vector, unsorted
  #  [[3]] integer vector showing the rank of each element of the original vector, in the sorted vector

  z <- is.na(N)
  Ch <- as.character(N)
  is.na(Ch) <- z
  negnumbers <- N < 0
  negnumbers[z] <- FALSE
  str.length <- nchar(Ch)
  n.digits <- ifelse(negnumbers, -(str.length - 1L), str.length)  # number of digits in each element, where for example -582 is deemed to have -3 digits
  r <- rank(n.digits, ties.method = "min")
  upr <- unique(r[!negnumbers]) # unique ranks of positive numbers in N
  unr <- unique(r[negnumbers])  # unique ranks of negative numbers in N
  for(s in upr) r[r == s] <- (s - 1L) + rank(Ch[r == s], ties.method = "min")
  for(s in unr) r[r == s] <- (s + sum(r == s)) - rank(Ch[r == s], ties.method = "random") 
  if(decreasing) r <- (1L + length(N)) - r
  list(sorted.bigz   = N[order(r)], 
       unsorted.char = Ch,
       ranking       = r)
}

sortbigz(X)
```